# Slow SVN synchronization in Eclipse with a multi-module Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, svnkit

We have a multi-module Maven project (an EAR project, configured similarly to [this one](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-in-ear)) in SVN, which we try to import in Eclipse (we tried both in Eclips Kepler or Eclipse Luna).

What we did is the following:
1. In terminal `svn checkout http://repository/ project`
2. Then in Eclipse "Import existing Maven projects"

The problem is that Svn synchronization is way too slow (I have tried both with SvnKit 1.8 and JavaHL 1.8). On every operation that it does, whether I want to commit a file, or to see all in- or outcoming changes in the "Team Synchronizing": it seems to fetch all files again and again.

I tried to close the parent project. Also I tried to change the settings in "Window" => "Preferences" => "Team" => "SVN" => "Performance", but it did not help much. Any other ideas?

Any answer that will help will be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using the Native JavaHL SVN Connector in Eclipse, where the performance problem is not so big.